# How to Split String into Array for multiple characters

Tags: vb.net

Here is my old script, in vb

```
Dim strArray As String() = str.Split(New Char() {":"C})
```

This works fine if the char is only :

But now I want to split for this,

:.++.:

As my str is complicated is there a way to split it ?

Edit :

My

> str = hello:.++.:sAwesome Right ? yeah://.,]['; :.++.:
>   nvijuds789g34huve02qjgv0b0whgvn0iegvb0wvi0hn

so after split

> strArray(0) = hello
>
> strArray(1)= sAwesome Right ? yeah://.,][';
>
> strArray(2) = nvijuds789g34huve02qjgv0b0whgvn0iegvb0wvi0hn

I think you see what I need. I am the one adding :.++.: before each part in previous functions. It is because the text almost contains every single character and I can't control it :/

thats why i used some complicated combination of characters to make it impossible for the file to contain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split a string by another string using the `String.Split` overload [(String(), StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("|", "A:.++.:B:.++.:C:.++.:D".Split({":.++.:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
```

Outputs:

> A|B|C|D

Comment: @PeresCudd My answer still stands. `str.Split({":.++.:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` returns the desired output.

Comment: My bad I tried it without the `, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

what does it do ?